# Scroll bar not appearing on ipad 3 for a div element

Tags: salesforce1-app, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

I am not able to get the scroll bar working for a div element. It works fine in all browsers, the issue is only on Salesforce1 app.

Any help would be great.Thanks in advance.

```
<aura:component>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/    </head>  
  <body>
        <div style="height: 130px;width: 200px;background-color:green;margin-right: 20px;overflow-y:scroll;-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;">
            <p> test</p>
            <p> test</p>
            <p> test</p>
            <p> test</p>
            <p> test2</p>
            <p> test</p>
            <p> test</p>
            <p> test4</p>
            <p> test</p>
            <p> test</p>
            <p> test5</p>
        </div>
</body>
</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the disappearing scroll bar is related to your view dimension. Try add this in your component's stylesheet. You can adjust the max-width to have a good view on tablets/phones

```
@media(max-width: 1600px){
    .THIS.container{
        width: 90%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard HTML "overflow:scroll" doesn't work in Lightning components.

But workaround is you can create a scrollDiv around your div in component and set the following in your css to make it work.

```
 .THIS div.scrollDiv {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use newly added Lightning component in the Winter '17, **ui:scrollerWrapper** that enables native scrolling in Lightning Components Salesforce1 app as well as in Lightning Desktop.

> A `ui:scrollerWrapper` creates a container that enables native
>   scrolling in Salesforce1. This component enables you to nest more than
>   one scroller inside the container. Use the class attribute to define
>   the height and width of the container.

Please find the **code** below:

**Component:-**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable, flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <div class="mainWrap">
        <ui:scrollerWrapper class="sWrapTest">
            <ul class="testDiv">        
               <li>In the Winter ’17 release, many of your favorite features 
                   are easier to use than ever before. 
               </li>
               <li>Lightning Experience has a brand new                      
                   navigation bar and lots of critical sales,
                   service, and analytics capabilities. 
               </li>
               <li>You’ve got more options for managing customer and partner
                   communities, running your business from your phone, 
                   and keeping your data and your users secure. 
               </li>
               <li>Not to mention plentiful new
                   customization and app development features, 
                   including custom Lightning apps.
               </li>                      
               <li>Other features require direct action by an administrator 
                   before users can benefit from the new functionality.
               </li>
               <li>If a key feature is also available in Salesforce1, 
                   our mobile app, we mention that in the feature description. 
               </li>
               <li>ui:scrollerWrapper
                   Creates a container that enables native scrolling in 
                   Salesforce1.
               </li>

            </ul>
        </ui:scrollerWrapper>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

**Style:-**

```
.THIS .sWrapTest {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
```